# elasticsearch check if the document exists using the id and if exists then update else create new one

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to check if the document is already exists using the `id`, if exists then need to update the entire document with new data otherwise have to create a new document. When I was looking the elasticsearch document there is an option to check using `HEAD` using `curl` but the response is not in `JSON` format, so its difficult to parse. Also I found there is a feature `scripted_upsert` which will create the document if its not there otherwise we can update the document field. But I don't see the option to update the entier document and that too I have to load that document data from the external `JSON` file.

Comment: When you pass id to index request, elasticsearch will automatically handle replacing the existing document.

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks